# Bind data from API to Dropdown in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I'm trying to populate a dropdown from a get API. I've created a service and using the observables returning the data to the component, which then subscribes to the service.
I'm able to console.log the whole data (which is in a JSON array) but I'm not able to see any data in the dropdown.

I guess the problem is that view is getting rendered before the API data. I know there is a resolve method but what else I can try?

My question and code are very much similar to the below question and there are few things which I've already correct in my code like 'Project' is an array but the solution isn't working for me. There is no error in my code also:

[Drop down does not populate with API data in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738984/drop-down-does-not-populate-with-api-data-in-angular)

Please find my code below:
**TestService.ts**

```
export class TestService {
  public testURL = 'https://test.url';
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

    getTypes(): Observable<TestModel[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'test': 'test1'});
    return this._http.get<TestModel[]>(this.testURL, {headers});
  }
  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './app-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-header.component.css']
})
export class AppHeaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   testModel: TestModel[];
   isLoaded = false;

  constructor(private _testService: TestService) { }

  getTypeT(): void {
    this._testService.getTypes().subscribe(data => {
      if(data) {
        this.testModel = data;
        this.isLoaded = true;
        console.log(this.testModel);
      }
    } );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // fetch all the survey types
    this.getTypeT();
  }
```

**component.html**

```
  <select  class="selectpicker dropdown mt-4 ml-3" id="type" data-live-search="true">
      <option *ngFor="let test of testModel" [value]="test.id">{{test.description}}</option>
   </select>
```

**Note**: I just figured out that problem seems to be with the "**selectpicker**" dropdown which is a third party plugin. Could you please suggest what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: It would be little difficult for me to post the code but my code is exactly similar to the link I've shared. Would it be possible for you to review that and let me know what is it that causing the problem? I'll still try to post my code tomorrow morning.

Comment: You could use the async pipe ( https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe ), and provide the observable with the data directly to the dropdown. That should work. :)

Comment: @SunilOjha if you have an issue with your code, then you should post your code. The question you posted is already answered, so if your code was the same, you should have no issue with that.

Comment: @GCSDC I've added the code for reference. Please note that there is no error in my code and I'm able to console.log correctly.

Comment: I've kind of figured it out. This seems to be a problem with selectpicker which is a plugin that I installed. Could you please suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: If you remove all attributes from the select, does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. I didn't remove only one attribute i.e. "selectpicker" class as I need this for dropdown to be displayed the way I want.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the async pipe.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './app-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-header.component.css']
})
export class AppHeaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   testModel: TestModel[];
   isLoaded = false;
   types$;

  constructor(private _testService: TestService) { }

  getTypeT(): void {
    return this._testService.getTypes();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.types$ = this.getTypeT();
  }
```

HTML

```
  <select  class="selectpicker dropdown mt-4 ml-3" id="type" data-live-search="true">
      <option *ngFor="let test of types$ | async" [value]="test.id">{{test.description}}</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Lars, I tried it but this isn't working for me.

Comment: If the dropdown itself is the problem - have you considered using another dropdown? Like Angular Material or something similar?

Comment: Hi Lars, I used a different dropdown today - ng-select and it worked alright. Thanks for your comment.